Is there a way to get more precice value-output without a divide math node after it?
Every so often when I setup a shader, I have this small extra setup, where I add a divide-node with a high number, after the value to get a more precise result. Even if it's simple, I wondering if there is way, to make it more elegant?
I'm aware of pressing shift while changing a parameter. I'm searching for a solution inside the node setup, because often I enter numbers directly.


you could make a group out of that two nodes....don't know whether that's more elegant ;)

When you say often you enter numbers directly, then I do not understand why you do not enter them as you need them? Your example 177.9 is only divided by 100... but even dividing by 100,000 is only 0.001779 which you could enter directly. Blender takes up to 6 decimal places (well, actually more but the next time you click in the field the value will be truncated to a value rounded to 6 decimals, see third paragraph). It might show only three in this case (0.002), but when you click in the field it will show all six.

Only when entering a number with 7 or more decimals the value will get rounded. For example putting a 0 more in front, 0.0001779 then in this case Blender does not show 0.002 but 0.000178 to indicate it was rounded to six decimals.

Although this is just half the truth. When you enter 0.0001779 it shows 0.000178, but plugging it into a Math node set to Multiply by 1,000,000 will give 177.9 as a result. So the original value is kept although displaying it rounded, however when you now click in the value field and it shows 0.000178 and hit Enter instead of Esc, the multiplied result will change to 178.0, because this works as if you now would have entered the rounded value directly.
Anyway. When entering values directly, it comes in handy that Blender accepts mathematical formulas as well. So when you want to divide some value, you do not need a Math node set to Divide - only if you want to change the numerator often or by some input while keeping the divisor. For simply entering some value, for example 177.9 divided by 1000, enter 177.9/1000 in the field and press Enter.

This is very comfortable if you want to enter values which are not so easily calculated in your head like the square root of 7 or $\pi$ divided by 3. Just enter sqrt(7) or pi/3 and hit Enter to get the value into the field.


So if you are not often using the same divisions, simply entering the values you need might be the simplest solution. If you often need to divide different values by the same divisor, the Divide node is the way to go. I think there is no more elegant solution to it (as Chris already commented, you could make it an extra node group, but then you would just switch one node for another). The only thing to make it slightly more elegant would be - when you know you're going to divide the value, why use a separate value in the first place? Instead of plugging it in the first Value socket of the Divide node, just enter the value there directly.

Summing it up, now these are three methods to get a value with a precision of 6 decimals:

Entering 0.001779 directly.
Entering 1779/1000000 (or 1.779/1000 or whichever combination of numbers suits you best)
Using a Divide node where you enter the values.

Those are the most simple methods I can think of, one might be better than the other depending on the situation as described above. I have no idea how a more elegant solution could look like (apart from specific cases like your example where you could enter the value directly into the texture's Scale field without the need of any extra nodes, but I guess this is valid for all setups where the resulting value is used to be plugged into something).
